# Finding existing module and then changing directory in Jupyter

Tags: python, neo4j, jupyter, graph-databases

I'm fairly new to Jupyter and Python but I've run into an issue that me nor my professor have been able to solve. I installed Anaconda on my Mac a few years back and it become too buggy to launch so I had to install python directly to my computer for use in class. I believe this somehow created two instances of Python/Jupyter.

I manually installed Neo4j graph database to my computer and then ran the following code in Jupyter:

```
!pip3 install neo4j
!pip3 install py2neo

from neo4j import GraphDatabase

database_name = "test_database"
username = "test_user"
password = "test_pass"
uri = "bolt://localhost:7687/" + database_name

driver = GraphDatabase.driver(uri, auth=(username, password))
session = driver.session()

print("Successfully connected to Neo4j!")
```

I then got an error from `neo4j import GraphDatabase` about not finding the Neo4j module even though I had installed the desktop version and created a database/password and everything with it.

I also tried `pip freeze` and saw that neo4j was not listed...

I then tried to uninstall anaconda in every way I could including the two ways outlined in [Nektony](https://nektony.com/how-to/uninstall-anaconda-on-a-mac) and [MacUpdate](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/62880/anaconda/uninstall) hoping that it would fix my issues, but with no success when I restarted the kernel and tried again.

I then entered `pip install neo4j-driver==1.6.2` in the terminal to see if that would fix things but instead it just changed the error to `ImportError: cannot import name 'GraphDatabase' from 'neo4j' (/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/neo4j/__init__.py)`. I notice it's still referencing anaconda in that error message.

**(1) - Is there any way to change the directory it's trying to find the module in?**

**(2) - If so, how can I find where to change it to?**

Any help is very greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: What is the version of your python and neo4j? Btw, module neo4j in python is different in py2neo and both can connect to neo4j database, so dont mix them up.